# How to fix TreeTagger : parameter file invalid : english.par in python

Tags: python

I need to have a TreeTagger for my project, I made the right import, pip install treetaggerwrapper was done, I placed it in my files

> (C:\Users\sfoxs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32)

, added it to the PATH...
I tried everything I could, but I keep getting this error.
I tried to place *english.par* in multiple path, but it still didn't work. I tried in *TreeTagger* , in *TreeTagger\lib* and also where my scripts are.
I'm out of idea, I can't solve it.
Do you have any idea where the problem could come from ?

In my code : I try to create a TreeTagger on a simple TestTree.py script :

```
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')
print(tagger)
```

Here is the error :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[If you installed TreeTagger in a non-guessable location, you still can set up 
an environment variable :envvar:`TAGDIR` to reference the
TreeTagger software installation directory](https://pypi.org/project/treetaggerwrapper/)

export TAGDIR='PATH-TO-TREETAGGER/TreeTagger'